# How should I properly shutdown my AndroidX Espresso test?

Tags: android, android-espresso, androidx-test

I am writing an Espresso test to test that my App Links are handled properly by my app. I've setup Android Studio and created a test that passes, but the problem is that the test suite hangs.  I have created a class, `LinkDispatcherActivity`, that is responsible for parsing the incoming links and dispatching their data to the appropriate activity. The tests are setup to use the `ActivityTestRule` to launch `LinkDispatcherActivity` and give it an intent with the URL to be tested.  The tests are running and passing, so I assume I've set everything up correctly (a challenge all on its own ).

I have tried using the new `ActivityScenarioRule` but can't figure out how to pass an intent to it.

Here's my test class:

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView
import androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.*
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import androidx.test.filters.LargeTest
import androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule
import gov.nih.nlm.wiser.R
import gov.nih.nlm.wiser.link.WiserLinkDispatcherActivity
import org.hamcrest.Matchers.allOf
import org.hamcrest.Matchers.instanceOf
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
class SubstanceLinkTest {
    @get:Rule
    val activityTestRule: ActivityTestRule<LinkDispatcherActivity>
            = ActivityTestRule(LinkDispatcherActivity::class.java, false, false) // initialTouchMode: false, launchActivity: false

    @Test
    fun shouldOpenLinkDispatcherActivity() {
        val i = Intent().apply {
            data = Uri.parse("https://mydomain/action?data=338")
        }

        activityTestRule.launchActivity(i)

        onView(allOf(instanceOf(TextView::class.java), withParent(withId(R.id.action_bar))))
                .check(matches(withText("My Title"))) // Passes!!
    }
}
```

Here's my added dependencies in by `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    // Core library
    implementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'

    // AndroidJUnitRunner and JUnit Rules
    implementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'

    // Assertions
    implementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.truth:truth:0.42'

    // Espresso dependencies
    implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.3'
}
```

Finally, here is what Android Studio shows in it's Run panel:
[image: Android Studio]

Cheers!

Edit:
Forgot to add that I'm getting this error in Logcat:

```
2019-06-21 12:02:24.326 6311-6035/? E/cckz: *~*~*~ Channel {0} was not shutdown properly!!! ~*~*~*
        Make sure to call shutdown()/shutdownNow() and wait until awaitTermination() returns true.
    java.lang.RuntimeException: ManagedChannel allocation site
        at cclc.<init>(:com.google.android.gms@17455040@17.4.55 (100700-248795830):1)
        at cckz.<init>(:com.google.android.gms@17455040@17.4.55 (100700-248795830):2)
        at ccdo.b(:com.google.android.gms@17455040@17.4.55 (100700-248795830):14)
        at rzc.a(:com.google.android.gms@17455040@17.4.55 (100700-248795830):43)
        at rzc.a(:com.google.android.gms@17455040@17.4.55 (100700-248795830):58)
        at atbl.a(:com.google.android.gms@17455040@17.4.55 (100700-248795830):9)
        at atbl.a(:com.google.android.gms@17455040@17.4.55 (100700-248795830):26)
        at qbi.run(:com.google.android.gms@17455040@17.4.55 (100700-248795830):1)
        at sgs.b(:com.google.android.gms@17455040@17.4.55 (100700-248795830):37)
        at sgs.run(:com.google.android.gms@17455040@17.4.55 (100700-248795830):21)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at smq.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

UPDATE: The test completes properly when run on a physical device.  Still not sure what's causing the emulator to hang.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an `@After` annotation with a method called something like 'tearDown'. You could do final assertions here and clean up any databases or processes that need to end and possibly call `publisher.shutdown();` and `publisher.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)` Hope this can help somewhat.

Check this thread out too:
 [https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/3648]